# Table background color gives illusion of colored border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rid of a blue border around my table cells. The color is the same as the background color of the table cells; I want the images to take up the entire cell, but can't figure out a way to get rid of these lines that look like borders. The idea is to make the background see-through by hovering over a cell. I link to the entire table in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgcu4j31/26/), but here is a snippet of code below.

CSS

```
.samples td{
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,300);
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
```

Comment: Supply the smallest example of the problem here, not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding: 0` to `td` and `display: block;` to `img` like this

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/rgcu4j31/39/)

```
.samples td {
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,300);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
    padding: 0;
}
.samples td img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.samples {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 z-index:50;
}
.samples table{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.samples td {
 text-align: center;
 width: 30%;
 height:300px;
 position:relative;
 table-layout: fixed;
 background-color: rgb(0,300,300);
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  padding: 0;
}
.samples td img{
  display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height:400px;
 z-index: 50;
}
.samples td:hover img{
 opacity: .5;

}
.samples p{
 margin: 0;
 position:absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 right:0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 z-index:10;

}
.samples td:hover p{
 visibility: visible;
}
.samples td p{
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="samples">
  <table>
    <th>Pokemon</th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Go Mustangs! Unfortunately, there's not much to cheer for...</p>
        <img src = "http://walnuthighschoolfootball.com/wp-content/uploads/2013-Clare_IMG_0257.jpg">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Hiking on Walnut's hilly Schabarum trail is a change from the Evanston pancake metropolis!</p>
        <img src = "http://nobodyhikesinla.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/hiking-2011-4-236.jpg">
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>Orange you hungry for a tangerine? Give me three and I'll give you a show</p>
        <img src = "http://juicyjuicevapor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/tangerines.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>My favorite place to nap</p>
        <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Deering_Library_detail_Northwestern.jpg">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>As a NU Quidditch beater/chaser, I enjoy dodging balls and scoring through hoops.</p>
        <img src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/513804815088885761/08UB6aL2.jpeg">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Have never played a game as great as Last of Us. The graphics are so realistic, and online multiplayer mode is v fun.</p>
        <img src = "http://media.aintitcool.com/media/uploads/2013/nordling/thelastofus.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```